# Facetgrid change xlabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

I just can't figure out how to change the `xlabels` in a Seaborn `FacetGrid`. It offers a method for changing the x labels with `set_xlabels()` but unfortunately not individually for each subplot.

I have two subplots which share the y-axis but have a different x-axes and I want to label them with different texts.

Comment: As per [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), it's better to directly use [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) functions like [`g = sns.relplot(data=tips, kind='scatter', ...)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) instead of `sns.FacetGrid`. The answers still work for this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can access the individual axes of the `FacetGrid` using the `axes` property, and then use `set_xlabel()` on each of them. For example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  hue="smoker")
g = g.map(plt.scatter, "total_bill", "tip", edgecolor="w")

g.axes[0,0].set_xlabel('axes label 1')
g.axes[0,1].set_xlabel('axes label 2')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note in this example, `g.axes` has a shape of `(1,2)` (one row, two columns).

Answer (score 0):

for all axis to set them once use this

```
g.set_axis_labels("Total bill ($)")
```

Comment: The question is about individual axes labels for each subplot, therefore, your answer is not working (I made the same mistake when I read the question),